# Play error: Unable to create injector

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to create a simple restful api using play and scala. I've been able to create some basic routes, get it to send back json responses, and validate json sent in a POST. Now I want to add persistence to a postgres database, which is where it's starting to break down.

I started off by adding the db info to my application.conf, creating an evolution to create a table. I then attempted to hit my GET endpoint to see if it runs the evolution, but I instead get an error. Here is the error output from the html (I was using my browser to hit the endpoint):

```
CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) A binding to play.api.db.DBApi was already configured at play.api.db.DBModule.bindings(DBModule.scala:25):
Binding(interface play.api.db.DBApi to ProviderConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.DBApiProvider)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1).
  at play.api.db.slick.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.bindings(EvolutionsModule.scala:15):
Binding(interface play.api.db.DBApi to ConstructionTarget(class play.api.db.slick.evolutions.internal.DBApiAdapter) in interface javax.inject.Singleton) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)

com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:466)
     com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:155)
     com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
     com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
     com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:168)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
     scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1423)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:902)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1644)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Here is my route (please note that I am not actually attempting to connect to the database yet):

```
GET     /cities                     controllers.CityController.index
```

Which connects to this controller method:

```
def index = Action {
    Ok(Json.obj("status" ->"OK", "message" -> "You did the thing!"))
  }
```

And here is my application.conf, comments removed for brevity:

```
akka {
}

play.crypto.secret = "changeme"

play.modules {
}

play.i18n {
  langs = [ "en" ]
}

play.http {
  session {
  }

  flash {
  }
}

play.server.netty {
}

play.ws {
  ssl {
  }
}

play.cache {
}

play.filters {
  cors {
  }

  csrf {
  }

  headers {
  }

  hosts {
  }
}

play.evolutions {
}

play.db {
  prototype {
  }
}

db {
  db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
  db.default.jdbcUrl="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/transit_service"
  db.default.username="redacted"
  db.default.password="redacted"
  db.default.logSql=true
}
```

My evolution is a fairly simple create table statement that lives under conf/evolutions/default/1.sql.

I would appreciate any insight into why this error is occurring and how I can get the evolution to actually run.

Comment: This issue is documented in the [Play Slick FAQ](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlickFAQ#A-binding-to-play.api.db.DBApi-was-already-configured). If you are using Slick for accessing your databases, remove the `jdbc` entry from the `libraryDependencies`.

Comment: could not understand the problem from the info you posted. If you didn't solve yet, I have a minimal Play + Slick example if you want to compare: https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps

Comment: Matthias Eckhart - That solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matthias Eckhart pointed out in a comment: Removing the jdbc entry from libraryDependencies in build.sbt was the solution to the problem.